# Yii large text translation

Tags: php, yii

is there a way to translate longer text in yii using i18n?

I think this is not a proper way to translate longer texts:

```
Yii::t('app','Longer text here...')
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Removed thanks. Needs description of the unexpected result of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate any long text as you want with Yii::t().

Another way is related tables with their content translate.

For example you want to translate news block. You create "news" table where you save general information for all languages for example images, category_id, url_name, creater_id, created_at etc.

Also you create "news_lang" table with one to many relations with "news" table. In new "news_lang" table you should have "news_id","lang_id","title","body", "meta_keyword","meta_description" etc. all translations you require. "news_id" column is related with "news" table "id" column. And each row of "news_lang" table match related language. "lang_id" also can be static and you can pass values with form hidden value or the better and flexible way is create "lang" table and relate it with translation tables.

Comment: Yes, but can I indent text with Yii::t()?

Comment: Probably you are using this app for web purposes with html. You can use <p> tags with all attributes(class, style etc.) for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to translate dynamic texts and get it with `Yii::t()` you can use [TsTranslation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tstranslation/) extension (you can download last version in [GitHub](https://github.com/TaronSaribekyan/TsTranslation/)).
It allow

- create and update dynamic content in different languages,
- get text using syntax `Yii::t($model, 'attribute')`,
- translate texts via Google Translate and more

DEMO and documentation: http://tstranslation.sundevelop.com/